# Dedupe users across grouped pages for Google Analytics in Looker/Data Studio

Tags: google-analytics, looker-studio

In Looker/Data Studio, I am wanting to display the number of Google Analytics **Users** that saw a page which contain the string 'SearchResults'. In the GA UI, I see two line items, with the overall number of **1,801** deduped. Great - this is what I am trying to create. So how do I create this in Looker Studio?

[image]

My first thought would be to create a Case Statement like this:

```js
CASE 
  WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(LOWER(Page),'searchresult') THEN 'Searches'
  ELSE 'Other'
END
```

...but when I do and use this in table with the User dimension, I get the sum of the two line items (1796 + 878 = 2674) and not the deduped number of 1,801.

[image]

*Additional Comments*

- In some ways I'm not surprised, the User metric is a pretty unique use case. But I hoping that GA and Looker Studio will play nice together seeing as they are both the same stack.
- Content Grouping in the GA UI would have been a nice idea, but I have a dashboard with years of historical data that I need to display and these Groupings are not retroactive.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Have you found a solution? Thanks.

Comment: Think I gave up after realizing for the umpteenth time that Data Studio is &$#@!